# Add & Subtract TR on Button Click (ID +1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I'm looking to have a table of products for an order form.

I would like the user to be able to add & subtract rows (adding & removing products w/ qty & remarks.)

I have pieced this together and works with a few exceptions.

- I need the ID of each input to +1 while val('') on the new inputs/row.
- The subtract button works but removes the last & only row. Removing itself & the add button with it.

Could anyone show me some examples of how I would +1 the inputs & have the subtract button show on the 2nd row? Or lead me in the right direction? Thanks in advance-

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" width="250px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="text-align:center;>
   <thead>
   <tr class="product">
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Item</strong></th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Qty.</strong></th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr name="product" class="product">
   <td width="100px" style="padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px;"><input type="text" width="100px" name="product" id="product" /></td>
   <td width="5px" style="text-align:center; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px;"><input type="text"maxlength="2" name="qty" id="qty"></td>
   <td width="100px" style="padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px;"><input type="text" name="remarks" id="remarks" /></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="+" style="width:20px; text-align:center;"/></td>
   <td><input type="submit" class="subtract" value="-" style="width:20px; text-align:center; display:none;"/></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

What I'm using now:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last #product').val('');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #qty').val('');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #remarks').val('');
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #add').val('+');


$("input.subtract").click(function() {
$(this).closest("tr").remove();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cloning, create a new `tr` with id equal to `$('#mytable tbody>tr: last')` id value + 1 and append it to table. To delete `tr` with specific id, use it as function parameter. In this function delete this specific `tr`. (`<input type="button" class="subtract" value="-" style="width:20px; text-align:center; display:none;" onClick="remove({id});"/>`)